# problemas com (array) objeto

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tenho um ***array*** de ***objetos***.

Ex.:

```
$array = array (1=$obj1, 2=$obj2...ect)
```

Acontece que estou convertendo esses **objetos** em **arrays** também para ter um ***array de arrays*** ao invés de um ***array de objetos*** com a finalidade de transformá-lo em um **`array JSON`**.

```
  $todos = $produtosDao->pesquisaProdutos(); 

  foreach ($todos as $cada):

     $produto[] = (array) $cada;

  endforeach;
```

Bom, quando faço `print_r($produto)`, tenho na tela o seguinte:
Obs.: vou colocar aqui apenas o primeiro registro para não ficar extenso o post ok?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ProdutosidProduto] => 1
            [Produtostipo] => mp
            [Produtosmodelo] => F540 2 BAN.PNEU. 100 X 60
            [Produtosbandejas] => 2
            [Produtospeso] => 0
            [Produtosprensagem] => 0
            [ProdutosprecoUnitario] => 6500
            [Produtoscomprimento] => 100
            [Produtoslargura] => 60
            [Produtoscabo] => 0
            [Produtosligacao] => n
            [Produtospotencia] => 0
            [Produtosconsumo] => 0
            [Produtoscorrente] => 0
            [Produtosdisjuntor] => 0
            [Produtosdescricao] => 
Valor promocional limitado frete grátis ,para SP ,RJ ,MG ,ES. Os demais será cobrado apenas de SP para sua cidade ,valor de 500,00 ,a ser pago na entrega .



MAQUINA TOTALMENTE INDUSTRIAL E 100% NACIONAL .PRODUÇÃO DE ATÉ MIL PÇS POR DIA EM HORÁRIO NORMAL DE TRABALHO ,SISTEMA DIGITAL AUTOMATIZADO DE ÚLTIMA GERAÇÃO , SISTEMA PNEUMÁTICO COMPACTO E UNIFORME RECEBENDO A MESMA PRESSÃO EM TODA ÁREA DE ESTAMPAGEM, EVITANDO ASSIM OS SOMBREAMENTOS E EFEITOS FANTASMA NA ESTAMPA , SISTEMA DE RESISTÊNCIA DE ALTA QUALIDADE A MELHOR DO MERCADO AÇO INOX 304 , DANDO UMA VIDA ÚTIL MUITO SUPERIOR AS DEMAIS DO MERCADO , E FÁCIL TROCAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS NÃO SENDO NECESSÁRIO TÉCNICO NO LOCAL , COM APENAS 4 PARAFUSOS O CLIENTE MESMO FAZ A TROCA, AS DEMAIS A RESISTÊNCIA É FUNDIDA NA CHAPA DE ALUMÍNIO SENDO IMPOSSÍVEL A TROCA APENAS DAS RESISTÊNCIAS , TEMOS TODAS AS PÇS DA PRENSA EM VALORES BEM ACESSÍVEIS. 
            [Produtosestoque] => 7
            [ProdutosfreteGratis] => s
            [Produtosbloqueado] => n
        )
```

Quando vou ver o código fonte, ***ctrl+u***, tenho o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Não fiz **Ctr+C** aqui pois quando vou colar os espaços estão sumindo.
Obs.: Note que na **printscream** temos espaços nos nomes dos índices.
Mas na saída do **print_r** não existe esse espaço.

Bom minha dúvida é a seguinte.

Estou precisando fazer um `str_replace` como recurso para excluir o espaço nos nomes dos índices da forma abaixo:

```
  var res1 =  Array(); 
  res1 = <?php echo str_replace("\u0000", "", json_encode($produto)); ?>;
  document.write(res1[0]["ProdutosidProduto"])
```

Gostaria de saber se existe algum recurso para que essa manobra não seja necessária.

Saída do script sem o `str_replace()`;

```
  var res1 =  Array(); 
  res1 = [{"\u0000Produtos\u0000idProduto":"1","\u0000Produtos\u0000tipo":"mp","\u0000Produtos\u0000modelo":"F540 2 BAN.PNEU. 100 X 60","\u0000P
```

Comment: Você só quer tirar os espaços? um `trim()` não resolve?

Comment: resolver não resolve pois tecnicamente NÃO há espaços. Só no Ctr+u eles existem. Logo o que se tem para retirar é \u000. Mas acredito que essa não deva sere a forma mais coerente de proceder. Já tentei adicionar os headers, html e php, para UTF-8 e não resolveu.

Comment: Teste esse map: `$keys = array_map('trim', array_keys($produto));$produto = array_combine($keys, $produto); `

Comment: obrigado @edson alves. O objetivo é usar apenas um header  charset que me livre dessas gabiarras. Entende? kkk. Mas como não tem, devo continuar com str_replace()

Comment: Estranho que o json_encode tenha enfiado esses espaços no seu array. Parece que tem algo modificando as keys

Comment: é exatamente isso que eu pretendo descobrir! Como eu já disse, já tentei até usando headers UTF-8

Comment: Taí o problema relacionado à sua pergunta anterior. Esses espaços é onde o parser do JSON está substituindo os espaços por \u0000. Eles não são visíveis no print_r, mas no código fonte sim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema parece ser na conversão para array, no código:

```
$produto[] = (array) $cada
```

Se você ler a documentação do PHP onde fala sobre arrays, mais especificamente na sessão ["Converting to Array"](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) vai notar que o PHP tem um comportamento diferente quando é feita conversão de uma objeto derivado de uma classe que não seja `stdClass`.

O que acontece é que o PHP cria, para cada propriedade do objeto, uma chave no novo array convertido. Porém esta chave é prefixada com o caracteres nulo (`\0`), o nome da classe serializada e o nome das propriedades. Onde:

- **public**: não altera o nome da propriedade. Ex.:

  ```
  public $teste = 'valor';
  ```

  Se torna:

  ```
  'teste' => 'valor'
  ```
- **protected**: prefixa o nome da propriedade com `\0*\0` (nulo + * + nulo). Ex.:

  ```
  protected $teste = 'valor';
  ```

  Se torna:

  ```
  "\0*\0teste" => "valor"
  ```
- **private**: prefixa o nome da propriedade com `\0NomeClasse\0`. Ex.:

  ```
  class MinhaClasse {
      private $teste = 'valor';
  }
  ```

  Se torna:

  ```
  "\0MinhaClasse\0teste" => "valor"
  ```

---

Entendo isso fica fácil formular um teste para ver o que está acontecendo com seu código:

```
<?php

class Teste
{
    public $prop_public;
    protected $prop_protected;
    private $prop_private;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->prop_public = 'public';
        $this->prop_protected = 'protected';
        $this->prop_private = 'private';
    }
}

$obj = new Teste;
$arr = (array) $obj;

print_r($arr);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    // converte \0 para \\0 para ficar visível
    $key_null = str_replace("\0", '\0', $key);
    echo "[$key_null] => $value\n";
}
```

<sup>[Código rodando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/PHP-Array-Convertion-Odds)</sup>

**Saída do `print_r`**:

```
Array
(
    [prop_public] => public
    [*prop_protected] => protected
    [Testeprop_private] => private
)
```

**Saída do `echo`**:

```
[prop_public] => public
[\0*\0prop_protected] => protected
[\0Teste\0prop_private] => private
```

---

Dessa maneira consigo saber que as propriedades da sua classe `Produto` são `private`, e como mostrado no código acima, você pode remover estes caracteres nulos usando:

```
str_replace("\0", '', $chave);
```

<sup>Note que deve-se usar aspas duplas no `\0` senão o PHP escapa a barra invertida</sup>

Se você estiver tendo problemas com unicode esta [resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4892995/1284458) faz desta maneira:

```
str_replace('\\u0000', '', json_encode($var));
```

---

Você ainda poderia checar a documentação da biblioteca que você está usando para acessar o DB e procurar por algum método `toArray()`, ou criá-lo para não ter que fazer gambiarras pra arrumar as gambiarras do PHP.

Comment: então, estou acessando com mysqli. Pensei que existisse algum recurso ao str_replace. Algo como um header utfg-8 ou alguma coisa parecida!

Comment: Como o problema é no PHP, em como o PHP converte um objeto para um array. Você poderia usar [mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) para pegar como array ao invés de objeto.

Comment: Mas o mysqli não atribui o resultado como `private` que eu saiba. Tem certeza que não tem uma classe sua com estes atributos como `private`?

Comment: não dá pois não tenho permissão de mexer no fonte pois é apenas para atender a requisição de uma aplicação mobile!
Mesmo assim, o site inteiro está feito com objetc

Comment: sim, todas as minhas classes uso atributos privados e faço chamada do tipo getAtributo() para recuperá-los

Comment: No Repl.it que eu fiz eu mostro como dar um replace no `\0`, é só fazer isso no seu código se não pode mexer no restante.

Comment: é eu sei. Mas estava procurando algum header mesmo. Mas já que não existe vou continuar como estava mesmo antes da pergunta

Comment: Não entendi porque você estava procurando um header, não faz sentido pra mim. Nenhum header pode esconder caracteres indesejados. De qualquer maneira, a resposta responde o porquê dos caracteres estranhos e acabei aprendendo no processo de criar a resposta também. Boa sorte :D

Comment: header (, UTF-8) Não é que esconde. Mas corrige caracters. Mas vou dar sua resposta como aceita por causa de que ela tem muito conteúdo útil!

Comment: Ela "corrige" se você estiver com problemas de encoding. E o seu problema é outro, por isso minha dúvida. Mas de qualquer maneira, que bom que pude ajudar de alguma maneira.